Setting Cookie No Longer Working After Deploy
After deploying both my backend written in Go (using railway) and frontend written using React (using Vercel) setting cookies no longer seems to work. This wasn't a problem when working with both of them locally, only after I deployed them.
For context, here is what sets the cookie:
    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "auth_token",
        Value:    tokenString,
        Expires:  expirationTime,
        Secure: true,
        SameSite: http.SameSiteLaxMode,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Domain:  domainName,
    })

This is the request I am making on the frontend:
      const res = await axios.post(api.login, formData, {
        withCredentials: true, 
      });


I'm expecting the cookie to be set in the frontend like it was when I was testing and working locally, however after deploying both frontend and backend it seems to not work.

Not sure if SameSite=Lax is the correct setting here, because that will make the cookie not be send for cross-site requests.

What are the Web origins of your frontend and backend? What is the value of domainName?

My backend is hosted on railway and my frontend is hosted on Vercel. the domain name is the domain for the hosted Vercel frontend. I tried SameSaiteNoneMode but it still was not working.

Removing the Domain field seemed to fix it and also changing it back to SameSiteNoneMode

I recommend you to use Gin, i already had this challenge to set cockies via http package.
here an example that how you can write :
package main

import (
"github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

func main() {
app := gin.Default()
app.POST("/login",loginHandler)

}


func  loginHandler(ctx *gin.Context) {
// add your business logic 
ctx.SetCookie("key", value , int(time.Now().Add(time.Minute*15).Unix()), "/", "", false, true)
// return what ever you want
}

by the way try to remove withCredentials: true from axios

Ensure you have cors configuration setup:
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://your-frontend-domain.com")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")

Ensure that the domainName in your http.SetCookie function matches the domain of your frontend. For example, if your frontend is hosted at frontend.test.com, your cookie domain should be api.test.com.
http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
    Name:     "auth_token",
    Value:    tokenString,
    Expires:  expirationTime,
    Secure: true,
    SameSite: http.SameSiteLaxMode,
    HttpOnly: true,
    Domain:  "api.test.com",
})


I ran into some similar issues and I fixed them by adding cors middleware. I specified the allowed origins, and added a default path to the cookie. You may need to change:
SameSite: http.SameSiteLaxMode to SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode

The situations in which Lax cookies can be sent cross-site must satisfy both of the following:

The request must be a top-level navigation. You can think of this as equivalent to when the URL shown in the URL bar changes, e.g. a user clicking on a link to go to another site.
The request method must be safe (e.g. GET or HEAD, but not POST).


Source: What is the difference between SameSite="Lax" and SameSite="Strict"?
The reason it may work in your localhost is because they will be viewed as the same domain, vs your deployed sites are now two different origins.
Your code might end up something like:
   http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "auth_token",
        Value:    tokenString,
        Path: "/",
        Expires:  expirationTime,
        Secure: true,
        SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode,
        HttpOnly: true,
        Domain:  domainName,
    })

